# extendTheme for Chakra-ui in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby, chakra-ui, gatsby-plugin

I am working in Gatbsy and when I try and override the core Chakra theme using a shadow `theme.js` file in a `gatsby-plugin-chakra-ui` folder it has no effect.

Any thoughts please? I am using

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/core'

const theme = extendTheme({
        components: {
                Input: {
                        variants: {
                                outline: {
                                        borderColor: 'blue.500',
                                },
                        },
                },
        },
})
```

EDIT: amending the theme works with the Button component, but not the Input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For customizing the Input element field, you just need to add the `field` property inside the `outline` object, like this way:

```js
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/core'

const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Input: {
      variants: {
        outline: {
          field: {
            borderColor: 'blue.500',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```